# Difference between blank and null constraints

Tags: grails, grails-orm

What is the difference between the blank and null constraints ?

I have the following class

```
class Task {

    String title
    String notes
    TekUser assignedTo
    Date dueDate
    TekEvent event

    static constraints = {
        title blank:false
        notes blank: true , maxSize: 5000
        assignedTo nullable:true
        dueDate nullable:true
    }

    static belongsTo = TekEvent
}
```

and the mysql table created has the notes set to not null even though I specified `notes blank : true`

What effect does blank : true have ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `blank:true` means the field accepts an empty string or one composed only by spaces as valid values. Eg: `""`, `"  "`
- `nullable:true` means the field accepts `null` as valid value

They can be used together. Eg:

```
title blank:false, nullable: true
```

Comment: but i am still unable to understand why  the column `notes` is set to `not null` in the table ?

Comment: By default Grails does not allow null values for properties (eg: nullable: false). If you want a null value you need to express it explicitly -> nullable: true

Comment: Therefore the constraints you might want for the notes column are: nullable: true, blank: true, maxSize: 500

Answer (score 6):

While the answer by aruizca is correct and descriptive, I found this while reading the book: "**Programming Grails**" by Burt Beckwith.

> **Blanks Versus Nulls**
>   In many cases, a blank string and null are
>   equivalent—there is no value set. But HTTP submissions from web
>   browser POST requests send blank strings for inputs without a value.
>   This will not be the case with non-HTTP data, such as from other
>   external clients like web services or during testing, so converting
>   blanks to nulls for the HTTP tier will help simplify validation. While
>   we’re at it, we can also trim extra whitespace from submitted
>   values.

It may not be relevant to your question. Aruizca's answer is all you need, but this can be an additional information about Blanks and Nulls.

Comment: This helped me pinpoint an issue with BootStrap generated test data: map constructor converts empty strings to nulls, so I had to set the property after the constructor call to satisfy the nullable:false, blank:true validation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The other answer are all correct, but to address your question:

> mysql table created has the notes set to not null even though I
>   specified notes blank : true
>
> What effect does blank : true have ?

`blank: false` protects empty values( e.g. "", " ", etc) from being set on that field. This has nothing to do with the field having the constraint `NOT NULL` on mysql. That happened because Grails constraints *default* to `nullable: false` on every field unless you explicitly set it to `nullable: true`.

Comment: does a field having constrain `nullable: false` accept empty string if `blank` constrain is not given?

Comment: Just checked, the default behavior is such that a blank string will not validate for `nullable: false` since the data binder will convert blank strings to null.