# When and why should nullable or/and blank constraints in a grails domain class?

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-domain-class

I am a bit new to grails and I'd like to get a clear understanding of how to use 'nullable' and 'blank' constraints in a grails domain class.

An example is;

> static constraints = {
>           name nullable: true
>       }
>
> static constraints = {
>           name blank: true
>       }
>
> static constraints = {
>           name nullable: true, blank: true
>       }

What do each of these mean and how best can they be applied?

Comment: Nullable:  think of it as fields that may not even appear on the web page as an input field to be captured.so you have String walletSize but don't display it when capturing the form input that walletSize is not even registered as a field that is being save so you save

new Person(name:name).save() 

But on another form you may have it and the user must enter something since if you then wish for them to leave it blank on the page then :
Blank when you actually present something lets say String name
The name field on the form page would exist but when the user can actually leave it blank

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203099/difference-between-blank-and-null-constraints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All properties are not-null by default, so generally the only time you use the `nullable` constraint is when you want to *allow* nulls, i.e. `nullable: true`.

Moreover, by default Grails databinding will convert blank strings to null, which effectively means that `blank: false` is applied by default (because blanks are converted to null, and nulls are prohibited).

There are some theoretical cases wherein it would be necessary to explicitly specify `blank: false`, e.g. if a property is set to a blank string after databinding. However, these are very unlikely to occur in practice, so ignoring some edge cases it's reasonable to assume that `blank: false, nullable: false` are applied by default.

Answer (score 1):

Well, **at first** you should look into the [docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html). 
Second: 
**Nullable** is already set by default to false. If you want some value to be nullable, then you write `name nullable: true`. 
**Nullable means** that when creating an object, that value can be left null (nothing inputted). 
**Blank** - when you will create i.e. form for objects param input and you left a field empty, it will save with no errors and accept empty value. 
Long story short - Blank is for forms to accept empty. Nullable is for the coded object to be saved without value. 
You can also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203099/difference-between-blank-and-null-constraints).